# THree.js: how to keep sprite text size unchanged when zooming from orthographicCamera

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, sprite

In three.js with orthographicCamera, when the mouse is zoomed, the Sprite will be magnified and reduced accordingly.

```js
var camera = new OrthographicCamera(width / - 2, width / 2, height / 2, height / - 2, 0.01, 100000);


var texture = new THREE.Texture( canvas );
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial ( { map: texture, transparent:false } );
var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );
scene.add(sprite);
```

How do you keep the text size from changing when the mouse is zoomed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're performing your zoom, since it could mean:

- Moving the camera in or out
- Making the camera's field-of-view narrower or wider

But I think you're looking for `SpriteMaterial.sizeAttenuation = false;` This keeps the sprite at a constant size, regardless of its depth in the scene. [See here for the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=sprite#api/en/materials/SpriteMaterial.sizeAttenuation) However, I believe this only works on perspective camera.